# Prove of limit related to $|f(x)|$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, epsilon-delta

Question:

Prove that if $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to a} f(x) = L$ then there is a number $\delta > 0$ and a number $M$ such that $|f(x)|<M$ if $0 < |x - a|< \delta$.

This means:

For every $\epsilon > 0$ and some $\delta > 0$

$|f(x) - L| < \epsilon$ for $|x - a| < \delta$

By the Reverse Triangle Inequality:

$\bigg| |f(x)| - |L| \bigg| < |f(x) - L| < \epsilon$ for $|x - a| < \delta$

$\bigg| |f(x)| - |L| \bigg| <\epsilon$ for $|x - a| < \delta$

$-\epsilon < |f(x)| - |L|< \epsilon$ for $|x - a| < \delta$

$\therefore |f(x)| < \epsilon + |L|$ for  $|x- a| < \delta$

Hence we let $M = \epsilon + |L|$

Is this how it is supposed to work? SO that $M \ne L$ but $|f(x)| < M$?

Thanks

Comment: you are right..

Comment: Of course, assuming $\;L\neq\pm\infty$

Comment: @Timbuc, that is an incorrect statement. That assumption is not required because infinity is not a real number hence L cannot equal infinity.

Comment: @Amad27 No where in your post you said $\;L\;$ is "a real number".

Comment: @Timbuc, it is a reasonable Presumption. Because $L = \infty$ or $L = -\infy$ is complete nonsense. A number cannot **equal infinity**. Hence it is certainly a reasonable presumption.

Comment: @Amad27 I think you don't understand: it could perfectly well, in the general case, that $\;\lim\limits_{x\to a}f(x)=\pm\infty\;$ . I **know** infinity is not a number. What isn't clear here?